# Doing work against back emf

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

Brushing up on my understanding of electrodynamics, using Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics(4th ed), I'm always questioning the magnitude of "energy" required/consumed in the process of doing work "against" back emf.

> **The work you must do against the back emf to get he current going, this is a fixed amount, and it's recoverable: you get it back when the current is turned off.**

$$\frac{\ d {W}}{dt} =-{\varepsilon I }= L I\frac{\ d {I}}{dt}$$

From $I$ = $0$ to a final value of $I$ the work done is now :

$$W = \frac{1}{2}LI^2$$

----      ***[Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics(4th ed) Pg.328](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGUif.jpg)***

It seems if we consider energy to be the "budget" of how much work can be done in a system, the majority of that "budget" is used to do work against back emf, since the energy lost due to heat can be reduced greatly, and the energy required to move charges( i/.e current $I$) is negligible, in addition, the emphasis of Lenz law in relation to Faraday's law, all points to that observation.

The work done to change the flux $\phi$ in such system, is the highest in magnitude and uses most of that "budget", I did an analysis on a problem, applying the conservation of energy, deriving it using Maxwell's equations(3&4) and Newton's laws as well.

I also attempted to model the system using Poynting's theorem, the observation is the same, most of the "work" or energy transferred is towards doing work against back emf to change the state of an electrodynamics system( $\Delta \phi$).

**1) Is that a fair observation?**

**2) Is there a "Reason" besides the experimental fact, as to why the majority of work done or energy consumed is for back emf?**

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: I've done that, and added a link to the image in case the reference is required, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is there a "Reason" besides the experimental fact, as to why the majority of work done or energy consumed is for back emf?*

This is true only under certain conditions, for example, when a circuit is dominated by an inductance, and is not true under many other conditions.

As you said, you can create these conditions by reducing the resistance. If, instead, you reduce the inductance, most energy will go into heating a resistor or charging a capacitor.

Comment: I can see that pattern, in a way... if the "volume" of the conductor was increased at the same $I$, I would assume that the resistance would decrease,leading to less energy converted and lost to heat, yet more of it is stored within the field and exhausted to do work against back, it's an amazing link, the larger the conductor becomes, and the more "power" is fed to it(specifically current) then the induction is also increased(due to the stronger magnetic field). From all the "accounting" of energy conversion, it seems that back emf is the main element that keeps the balance in-check. Correct?

Comment: @Pupil It you take a piece of straight wire, it'll have certain inductance and cert. resistance. You can increase the volume of the wire by making it longer or by making it wider. In the first case, inductance and resistance will increase, in the second - both will decrease. It you make a coil from the same wire, the inductance will increase, while the resist. won't change. So, it depends. It is true that, when resistance is very low, the inductance limits the rate of current change and, in this way, keeps it in check, but in many other cases, the role of inductance and back emf is limited.